# command not found: xsel -ob

Tags: linux, shell-script, zsh, youtube-dl

I'm using Manjaro Linux. [I've changed my yt-dlp's zsh configuration](https://git.disroot.org/hirrolot19/dotfiles/commit/aefb950b3a6f5ddcb6504d093ef96bfca6013ead#diff-6a0a53cfa400a5b85f7791056115eb86a4e7c783) and now I get

```
❯ ytvp
deal_with_long_filename:1: command not found: xsel -ob
deal_with_long_filename:2: command not found: xsel -ob
```

The log shows

```
Usage: yt-dlp [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

yt-dlp: error: no such option: --continue
  --no-overwrites
  --no-post-overwrites
  --verbose
  --restrict-filenames
  --retry-sleep fragment:exp

Usage: yt-dlp [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

yt-dlp: error: no such option: --continue
  --no-overwrites
  --no-post-overwrites
  --verbose
  --restrict-filenames
  --retry-sleep fragment:exp
```

Why is it treating all options as a single one?

I've tried running the `xsel -ob` command on its own and it works fine.

How do I fix this?

I would like to keep the send to background `&` option that I was using. Would it give problems with the definition of the function `deal_with_long_filename`?

This is my configuration now

```
opts="--continue
  --no-overwrites
  --no-post-overwrites
  --verbose
  --restrict-filenames
  --retry-sleep fragment:exp=2:64
  --print-to-file"

if [ -f /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl ]; then
  yt_dlp="/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp"
else
  yt_dlp="$(which yt-dlp)"
fi

# If using Mac
if [[ "$(uname -a | awk '{print $1}')" == "Darwin" ]]; then
  paste="pbpaste"
  opts="${opts} --ffmpeg-location /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
else # If using Linux
  paste="xsel -ob"
fi

sanitize_linux_filename() {
  echo "$1" | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/_/g'
}

get_log_name() {
  TIMESTAMP=$( date +%y%m%d%H%M%S )
  NAME=$( sanitize_linux_filename "$1" )
  echo "yt-dlp_${TIMESTAMP}_${NAME}.log"
}

deal_with_long_filename() {
  if ! $yt_dlp $opts --output "%(upload_date>%Y-%m-%d|)s%(upload_date& |)s%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" "$($paste)" >> "/tmp/$LOG_NAME" 2>&1; then
    $yt_dlp $opts --output "%(upload_date>%Y-%m-%d|)s%(upload_date& |)%(webpage_url_domain)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" "$($paste)" >> "/tmp/$LOG_NAME" 2>&1
  fi
}

# Video Playlist
ytvp() {
  LOG_NAME=$( get_log_name "$1" )
  opts="${opts}
    --format '(bv+(wa[abr>=64]/ba))/b'
    --format-sort res:720,tbr~2000
    --no-playlist
    --download-archive 'downloaded.txt'"
    
  deal_with_long_filename "$1" "$LOG_NAME"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct, there is no command called `xsel -ob` on your system.  The command you're trying to use is `xsel`, with its `-ob` options.  Since you put the command in a string, it's treated as a single entity.

The issue is similar to the issue described in [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Do store a collection of ordered strings in such a way that they can be used as separate strings, use an array.

```bash
opts=(
  --continue
  --no-overwrites
  --no-post-overwrites
  --verbose
  --restrict-filenames
  --retry-sleep fragment:exp=2:64
  --print-to-file
)
```

To add to an array:

```bash
opts+=( --ffmpeg-location /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg )

# ...

opts+=(
  --format '(bv+(wa[abr>=64]/ba))/b'
  --format-sort res:720,tbr~200
  --no-playlist
  --download-archive 'downloaded.txt'
)
```

Then, in the `zsh` shell, use it as `$opts`.

You also have the same issue with your `paste` variable, which should also be an array since you might want to treat it as the two strings `xsel` and `-ob`:

```bash
paste=( xsel -ob )
```

There are a number of other things in your script that are needlessly complicated, like using `uname` to get the OS type:

```bash
if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then ...; fi
```

... or using `sed` to remove certain characters from a string:

```
NAME=${1//[^[:alnum:].-]/_}
```

Comment: I get the exact same error for the options after applying this changes. The `command not found` is solved though. https://git.disroot.org/hirrolot19/dotfiles/commit/f5661648890cc933f56ecf61dddf0fcadd596c25#diff-6a0a53cfa400a5b85f7791056115eb86a4e7c783

Comment: @DevLloyd That's because you still use $opts as a string further down in the code.

Comment: So to use it I should do `$opts` instead of `${opts[@]}`? How can I add the last options if I don't use it as a string? `>> "/tmp/$LOG_NAME" 2>&1 &`

Comment: @DevLloyd No, what I meant was that in the functions further down in the code, in `yts` and the other two functions, you do `opts="${opts} ..."` when you should be doing `opts+=(...)`.